# Why Kotlin doesn't show kotlin.Unit for main function, unlike other functions having Unit return type?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and while trying the programs when I included functions with Unit return type it showed kotlin.Unit after completion of execution.

Being main function has Unit return type too why it doesn't show kotlin.Unit after execution?

```
a
b
c

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This was the output I got for simple program without any other functions

Comment: I don't understand why do you want a Unit return type. main doesn't have a Unit return type. in your function you have a return type 'Unit' but your function doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: `Unit` is completely optional and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

But to answer your question: Kotlin is printing the `Unit` result of calling your function *because you're telling it to*:

```
print(compare(a, b))
```

There's almost never a need to print `Unit`or manipulate it in any way, but that's perfectly legal to do.  And since your `main()` function also returns `Unit`, you could print that out too if you wanted (and were calling that from another function).  But why would you want to?

Either remove the `print()`, and simply call `compare(a, b)` on its own; or change `compare()` to return a value that you *do* want to print!